# How to determine deep in the React view hierarchy whether to use a Link or a callback?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React search component that a few levels deep in the search results row/column value has a ReactRouter.Link that will get the user to the Details page.
However I'd like to reuse this component in a dialog to search and select, in which case when clicking on the column value in that row I'd like to invoke the callback passed to the top parent. How do I deal with the fact that I need to specify the callback at a fairly high level and then act on it many levels down the hierarchy, other than passing it along ? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to define callback once without passing it via props, consider using [Context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the context, that way you can pass data to the children without using props, for example:

```
class ParentClass extends Component {
  // Define the data types that will be available for the children
  static childContextTypes = {
    link: PropTypes.string
    callback: PropTypes.func,
  };

  // defines the data value that will be propagated 
  getChildContext() {
    return {link: '/path/to/anywhere'};
  }
}

class ChildItem extends Component {
  // Define the data you want to receive from
  // parent context
  static contextTypes = {
    link: PropTypes.string
    callback: PropTypes.func,
  };

  render() {
    const { link, callback } = this.context; // <---- Get the data!
    return (
      <Link to={link} onClick={callback}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Link>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, you need to define the data that you want to pass to the children in the parent component, then define the data that you want to receive in the children and get it from the context.

I hope this helps.